# Mini workflow on status in plsql oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, ifs

I tried to make mini workflow for status in application.
 
If i have one status of a issue then i can change it only on one defined 
else you get a information from application that You can't change it 
code is compiled and used by application caled IFS ERP 
i think it is simple but i have few errors when the trigger is on

for example: 
Failed executing statement (ORA-06550: linia 3, kolumna 27:
PLS-00201: identifier 'WORKDONE' must be declared

```
Declare

status_old varchar2(20) :=&OLD:WO_STATUS_ID;
status_new varchar2(20) :=&NEW:WO_STATUS_ID;

begin 
if status_old like 'WorkRequest' and status_new not like 'UnderPreparation'  then
IFSAPP.Error_SYS.Record_General('C_PURCH_REQ_SUB1','You can't change status on  W przygotowaniu ');

ELSIF

status_old like 'UnderPreparation' and status_new not like 'Prepared'  then
IFSAPP.Error_SYS.Record_General('C_PURCH_REQ_SUB1','You can't change status on  Przygotowane ');

ELSIF

status_old like 'Prepared' and status_new not like 'Released'  then
IFSAPP.Error_SYS.Record_General('C_PURCH_REQ_SUB1','You can't change status on  Aktywowane');

ELSIF

status_old like 'Released' and status_new not like'Started'  then
IFSAPP.Error_SYS.Record_General('C_PURCH_REQ_SUB1','You can't change status on  Rozpoczęte ');

ELSIF

status_old like 'STARTED' and status_new not like 'WorkDone'  then
IFSAPP.Error_SYS.Record_General('C_PURCH_REQ_SUB1','You can't change status on  Wykonane');

ELSIF

status_old like 'WorkDone' and status_new not like 'Reported'  then
IFSAPP.Error_SYS.Record_General('C_PURCH_REQ_SUB1',' You can't change status on Odebrane');

end if;

end;
```

Is it possible to make it simplier ?

Comment: why do you use  `&` and where the value `&NEW:WO_STATUS_ID`  will be set?

Comment: What is the statement actually being executed, that throws that exception? It looks like it might be coming from an anonymous block rather than a trigger (and it would be helpful to include the full trigger code, not just the modified PL/SQL part, perhaps; assuming this is actually the trigger you refer to).

Answer (score 1):

you should mask a `'` in a string.

replace `can't` by `can''t`

further note:
in the like pattern should always be '%' or '_'

Comment: ofcourse :) i just translated it from polish to english - the error statement will be in Polish language

Comment: your example does not correspond to reality then. d
Your error is in line 3, but there is no WORKDONE in line three. is this the code that causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this nested `if ... else ...` with partially repeated values you can use table of varchars (type) and check if old status matches corresponding next status. Like in this sample function:

```
create or replace function stat_change(i_old in varchar2, i_new in varchar2) 
  return number is

  v_ret number(1) := 0;
  type t_stat is table of varchar2(20);
  v_stat t_stat := t_stat('WorkRequest', 'UnderPreparation', 'Prepared', 
                          'Released', 'Started', 'WorkDone', 'Reported');
begin
  for i in 1..v_stat.count - 1 loop
    if v_stat(i) = i_old and v_stat(i + 1) = i_new then 
      return 1;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return 0;
end stat_change;
```

Test:

```
select stat_change('WorkDone', 'Started') from dual;  --> 0
select stat_change('Started', 'WorkDone') from dual;  --> 1
select stat_change('XYZ', 'PQR') from dual;           --> 0
```

Powodzenia.